# How do I get a function to refer to the cell it is residing in?

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a function and I need the function to refer to a cell offset from where it resides in. I've got rows of data with each column containing a specific variable. The function resides in the last column, and is supposed to check if each variable defined in it matches the variables in the row preceding it. Each match is supposed to score a +1 to the final value of the function. Here's a short version of my function.

```
Public Function cellscore(testvar1)
totalscore = 0
If testvar1= activecell.Offset(-1, -10) Then
cellscore = totalscore + 1
End If
End Function
```

What do I replace activecell with, so that the function runs correctly for each row of data that I have?

I'm new at VBA so please bear with me if this is a simple question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Application.Caller.Address`?

Comment: Oh my. That was simple. It works, thanks a million! I was trying to use Cells or Range all this while, and they didn't work out.

Comment: FYI, if you're going to do that you need to make the function volatile or it won't recalculate properly. It would be better to pass all the ranges you need as direct arguments.

Comment: The answer is: don't do that; it will be a mess. Instead, pass the other value to the function as an argument. Declare function as: `Public Function cellscore(testvar1, otherValue)` and call it e.g. like this: `=cellscore(1234,A1)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to pass a numeric value to the function which represents the row number. This means that your code would become something like:

```
Public Function cellscore(testvar1,RowNum as Long)
totalscore = 0
If testvar1= Range("SOMECELL").Offset(RowNum-2, -10) Then
cellscore = totalscore + 1
End If
End Function
```

You will need to change **SOMECELL** to represent the cell in the first row. For example if your formula is placed in the **T** column, then you would replace **SOMECELL** with **T1**.

The clever part now comes with how you call the function within the worksheet. You do this by using the formula:

```
=cellscore(SOMEVALUE,ROW())
```

Obviously replace **SOMEVALUE** with the value you are testing for. Now regardless of which row this formula is placed it will reference the current one when calling the function. Hope this helps!